# In the "Hunger Games" series, how long has Snow been president?

Tags: the-hunger-games

I've been wondering, how long has President Snow been president when the "Hunger Games" books (or movies) take place? Given the described medical possibilities, a 75-year presidency doesn't seem unreasonable, but is it explicitly mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't recall Collins ever stating it in interviews, but it must have been at least 25 years since President Snow had Haymitch's mother, younger brother, and girlfriend killed after the Second Quarter Quell, which was the 50th Hunger Games.

As you noted, the medical technology in The Hunger Games is advanced but the Hunger Games wiki claims [President Snow is 76 years old](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/President_Coriolanus_Snow), which would imply to me that there was at least one other ruler of Panem after the 1st rebellion.

Answer (score 2):

Snow had been President of Panem for at LEAST 25 years, as it was mentioned that he was presiding over the nation when Haymitch won the 50th Hunger Games (the trilogy takes place with the 74th and 75th Hunger Games, before the second rebellion and the overthrow of the Capitol). It is HIGHLY doubtful (as some have suggested) that President Snow was leading Panem for the past 70 + years leading up to the Hunger Games Trilogy. The Hunger Games Wikia mentions President Snow being in his mid-70s, age-wise, so he had to have at LEAST one predecessor. That's all we know, as the details of Panem's history is largely unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

He would've become President at some point between the 10th and 50th hunger games, as he is around 18 years old during the 10th, and it is stated that he was President in Haymitch's games. As he spent the summer after the 10th hunger games in District 12 as a Peacekeeper, and then was studying at University with the Head Gamemaker at the time, Dr. Gaul, and later became a Gamemaker himself, it is fair to assume he became President many years after the 10th Hunger Games, but most likely before the 50th. The President during the first Hunger Games, was Presidetn Ravinstill, and he was President during the 10th Hunger Games, however even at this point he had grey hairs, so it is safe to assume Snow became President earlier rather than later, unless there was someone else splitting up the time between the 10th and 50th hunger games. These are deductions I have made from The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes, and from the original Hunger Games trilogy :)

Comment: This is a nice broad overview, have you got any quotes you could [edit] in to back up your points made though?